# xUnit C# code snippets to speed up testing creation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit.net

I am using `xUnit` to test some existing C# project.
I would like to speed up my test creation with code snippets.

I looked into `Viusual Studio` => `Tools` => `Code Snippets Manager` and I could not find anything, but maybe I missed something.

Does anybody know if there are some default code snippets for `xUnit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio extension [xUnit Code Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsakamoto.xUnitCodeSnippets) comes with snippets to create test methods and test classes (among other things).

You can also always create your own snippets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2022

Consider creating a pull request in the [xUnit Code Snippets GitHub repo](https://github.com/jsakamoto/xUnitTestCodeSnippets) in case you come up with some helpful snippets.